Young adult growing up in a poor neighborhood in Scotland
It's about young  adult (15 year old) growing up in a poor neighborhood (in 80ies or later), spend his life fighting with other gangs. His drunk father beat his mother. The guy wants to kill his father. He beats him, his father hopes also to die. He stabs the leader of the other gang. At the end, hopeless he tapes to his hand knives in a suicide mission over other gangs. 
ps: it's not ratcatcher, sweet sixteen
EDIT : Changed in the title "England" with "Scotland"

Is this a movie?  Note there are various tags with 'identify' in them.  It might pay to add one.

This is Peter Mullans' criminally overlooked Neds.

The only discrepancy is that the film is set in Scotland, not England, but still part of the UK. 
The film is set in 1970's Glasgow, where the protagonist is a 'Ned', the local colloquialism for hooligan.
His father is; 

an alcoholic wife-beater who works as a tool maker.

and at the end of the movie:

John's father asks him to put him out of his misery and end his life. John goes to his room and prepares two knives which he tightly straps to both hands. He goes downstairs and his father - whilst urinating in a bottle - asks him to wait until he is asleep. John decides to go for a half naked walk in a self-destructive mood. He comes across the rival gang and viciously attacks one of them, injuring him badly. John is then pursued by the other gang members and is badly beaten in turn.


That's it! I can't believe you fund it! Thanks a lot! And for all your info about it!

I'm quite confuse about the distinction between "england" and "scotland", I heard about traditional tensions between those "regions", but is scotland not a part of england? And what's the difference between "UK" and "England"? Would you call both "province" like in Canada, or "state" like in US? I'm aware that thos could sound naive but for most french  "england" and "UK" are synomym, and Scotland is a region. I guess it's because we dont have (yet) that concept of "state" or "province", we got "region" but it doesnt really mean anything.

Sigh... from what you're saying, it sounds like they just tell you Horse***t in Canada! None of what you've said is accurate. Scotland, England, Wales and Northern Ireland are four separate countries, referred to together as the British Isles, or Great Britain. England, Wales, Scotland and Northern Ireland are (currently) ruled by one legislative authority, (Parliament) so they are referred to as the UK. 'Britain' is the name of the physical island itself, so whilst Northern Ireland is part of Great Britain, it isn't part of Britain (the Island).

Northern Ireland is part of mainland Ireland, but is ruled by the British Government (UK Government), which has caused a lot of problems in the past with the IRA, who think it should be given back to Ireland. Scotland has a devolved parliament, meaning it can make some of its own decisions locally and has its own distinct money, although it is still part of The Pound (it just looks different). There isn't any real tension between Scotland, England or Wales, other than the artificially produced tension Alex Salmond propagandizes to push for Scottish Independence.

So, really, if you wanted to edit your question, it should be poor Neighbourhood in 'Scotland', 'Uk' or 'Great Britain' (as they are overlapping [but different] concepts), but definitely not England. I suppose it's quite complicated to figure out without looking at a map, and most people here are ignorant of the distinction anyway...

What you refer to as 'regions' or 'provinces' we call 'Counties', and they can be very small indeed or quite large. (they come from original Feudal boundaries of Dukes/Lords, so some are much bigger than others). Anything with 'Shire' (pronounced Shur) at the end of it is referring to a County, and not a place per-se. So you have Lancashire, Yorkshire, DerbyShire, and these counties have their old vestigial capitals, where they take their name from: Lancaster, York and Derby.. etc. etc.

thanks a lot for your answer! I'm not Canadian, but worst: I'm french (nobody is perfect, right!). I still don't get it: how could you have "four separate countries" "ruled by one legislative authority, (Parliament)"? If spain and Italia were rule by the same parlement, they would be the same country. "Country" does not rules by itself by definition? (notice that I'm not judging the thing, I'm just curious about it)

Think of it like the Roman Empire (or indeed, the British Empire!) The Romans conquered Gaul, Germania etc.. all were ruled by Rome, but that didn't make them all Italy.

"What you refer to as 'regions' or 'provinces' we call 'Counties'" so would you call Scotland a "county" or a "state" like in US? According to google definition it can't be called a country since def: "a nation with its own government, occupying a particular territory".

Scotland, England, Wales are Northern Ireland are all Countries, with their own counties within their constituency. They all have their own flags. Scotland has a devolved parliament meaning it can make local decisions, but ultimately owes fealty to the British Parliament. Scotland has its own 'Shires', which are the equivalent to states: Aberdeenshire, Ayrshire, Midlothian. etc.

Actually, according to wiki and other website you are righ. Scotland is a "country", but not an "independent country" which make it so strange. http://geography.about.com/od/politicalgeography/a/scotlandnot.htm  it's fascinating.

Of course I'm Right, I'm never wrong. :-) ha ha, but seriously, I'm from the UK and took an A-level in Domestic Government and Politics, so I think I'm pretty unimpeachable in my description of the principality of the UK (Pulls smug face). When you live here its no big deal: There are regional and national identities even within England (Geordie, Cockney, Scouse, Manc) so we naturally break ourselves up into cultural identities: I'm sure its the same in France: It's what Freud called The Narcism of Small Difference... that's all that's going on.

so Freud was not that dump! (we start to fed-up around here about psychoanalytic obscurantism, your teacher should update with CBT, they are late!) Don't forget to be more glad when you admit a "failure" than when you "win", it's more challenging & noble since its rare, extremely rare. I like your humor, I wish you the best in your way and thanks again for all your explanations!

I've been taught both, Lisa! You just have to cherry pick the best bits from each approach, I suppose. Whilst most psychoanalysis, I agree, is outdated, it still has some incredibly insightful elements. To disregard all of Freud is to, as we say in England, 'Throw the baby out with the bath-water'. I hope that doesn't get lost in translation! ha ha. Hope you've a better understanding of the sovereignty of the British Isles! Good luck.

You know what? I just found this absolutely awesome video that does a really thorough job of explaining all the little details, if you're still unsure, it should help explain whatever I've missed...its also quite funny.

the video is super! About psychanalyse: it was not based on scientific fact, (it's started to be treated as a scam in some countries like Sweden). Do we really need to study alchemy when we learn chimistry, or theology with philosophy?
